# Ubuntu One - Stuck at Loading

Tags: ubuntu-one, cloud

just installed Ubuntu One on brand new 11.10.
When I open the control panel it stays Loading... and won't let me access my account, devices and folders. It states my files are synced, though.

Ubuntu One is in Italian.

Opening from Windows everything is OK.

Thanks in advance for your help

Fabrizio

Answer (score 1):

Try to open the ubuntu one settings and check for similar files and folders ubuntu wont delete an old file with a newer.

Comment: The problem is right there: I can't access the settings.. It acts like it can't connect. After like 5-10 minutes a message tells me to check my internet connection...

Comment: Ohh Thats bad, you can try to reinstall the ubuntu by remove it and install it with software centre, hope it helps.